Estimating energy of tidal friction in alternative moon scenarios
The moon loses kinetic energy due to tidal friction. I would like to quantitatively explore the energies involved in alternative earths in which the moon is larger or has a different orbit.
I asked an AI for insight and it said

The estimated rate of kinetic energy loss of the Moon due to tidal friction is approximately 3.7 terawatts (3.7 x 10^12 watts). This energy is dissipated as heat within the Earth's oceans and solid body due to friction caused by the tidal bulges.

And it says that I need to look at


Newton's law of gravitation
Navier-Stokes equations for fluid dynamics (for modeling ocean tides)
Solid mechanics equations for deformation and dissipation in the Earth's interior
Orbital mechanics equations for the Moon's motion
Dissipation factors or quality factors (Q factors) to account for energy dissipation


That would be overdoing it! But I do want a rough quantitative model.
For my purposes, it would be enough to have the "shape" of the overall equation in terms of linear, quadratic, or such terms.
For example, if the moon was 10x heavier, its gravity would be 10x stronger. Does that mean the energy lost to tidal friction is 10x greater? Or if the tidal bulge is 10x higher perhaps its volume is 1000x greater so the energy loss would be 1000x greater?
Or, perhaps the roughness of the earth's surface matters a lot if high tide is shallow, and the sloshing causes a signficant temperature change, but if the tide is more than a few metres deep, the roughness of the earth's surface makes almost no difference at all. Perhaps the energy loss curve flattens off suddenly once the tide reaches a critical depth.
Is there a single equation which bundles all this stuff up in terms of the mass and orbit of the moon, and some measure of the shape of the earth's surface? Or perhaps a couple of equations for different regimes?
Also is the 3.7TW figure above verifiable?

This kind of viscous fluid dynamics stuff is incredibly unintuitive and user-unfriendly, and I rather suspect that most (and probably all) people on this particular site will not be able to help very much with it. You may have more luck with the physicists or mathematicians, but honestly you may as well sacrifice a chicken to Navier and Stokes and use the shape of the entrails to estimate a power. It'll be a lot quicker than trying to do it the hard way, no-one else will know enough fluid dynamics to contradict you, and you can get a nice meal out of it.

This Wikipedia article cites Munk & Wunsch (1998) as the source for the 3.7 TW figure. They say 3.7 TW is known from astronomical data, i.e. the change in orbit of the Moon and slowing of Earth's rotation, and that "nearly all of this has traditionally been allocated to dissipation in the turbulent bottom boundary layers of marginal seas." They mention abyssal mixing may account for 0.6-0.9 TW, but the bottom boundary of marginal seas (shallow seas near continents) still appears to be the main factor.
So I guess what matters then is the speed of the tidal flow of water in those bottom boundary layers. According to this article, "In turbulent flow, losses are proportional to the square of the fluid velocity, V^2." I'd assume this would hold for frictional losses in shallow seas as well as it would for water in a pipe. The Darcy-Weisbach formula mentioned in the same article says frictional losses in a pipe are proportional to V^2/D where D is pipe diameter. For tides the "pipe diameter" would be the depth of the ocean, and I'm guessing tides are small enough that we can assume ocean depth is constant for this purpose.
So we just need V. To estimate V we could imagine a tidal river. The water must flow from the ocean into the river and back out with every tide. The distance it flows is proportional to the height of the tide, and it must do this roughly twice a day. So, we could suppose V is just proportional to the height of the tide (assuming the length of the day is unchanged).
This source says that from computing equipotential surfaces, the height of the tide is roughly proportional to m/r^3, where m is the mass of the moon and r its distance from Earth. A weirdly difficult fact to find - most sources only mention the formula for tidal force (which also happens to be proportional to m/r^3) not the height!
So anyway. Frictional losses from the tides are proportional to V^2 ∝ (m/r^3)^2 = m^2/r^6.
There's another way to estimate it. Presumably the frictional losses are proportional to the work done by the tide. The work done by the tide is Force * Distance, where the force is proportional to m/r^3, and the distance is proportional to the tidal height, which is also proportional to m/r^3. So we get m^2/r^6 in two different ways.
